# StoreKit 2: cancellation button

Tags: ios, swiftui, storekit2

I have auto-renewable subscriptions in my app. I've been using `.manageSubscriptionsSheet` to present a user with a variety of subscriptions and a possibility to cancel the current subscription. Now, I'm trying out the new StoreKit 2 (available in iOS 17.0+) - and it works great (and also looks nice), but it doesn't seem to support cancellation... I tried different options and couldn't make it show anything related to "unsubscribing".

One of the options I've tried was adding `.storeButton(.visible, for: .cancellation)` - but it doesn't seem to do anything.